# Need to find 3 small errors - memory bugs

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, access-violation

As part of a college assignment, we were tasked with analyzing some code in an effort to identify memory issues. There's 3 we are to find. As I am quite new to the concept of pointers, I am drawing a blank. I do know main() should be returning an int and that the use of the "unsigned" means non-negative integers in this case.

[Compiler Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggwnz.jpg)

Tried searching for similar problems.

```
void main()
{
    double* d = new double;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        d[i] = 1.5 + i;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << d[i] << endl;
    }
}

The program results in an infinite loop of memory addresses.
```

Comment: Most of those warnings are pretty clear. What are you struggling with in particular?

Comment: most often, memory bugs are either memory leaks (allocating memory without releasing it) or accessing the memory in an incorrect way (e.g. dereferencing pointers to memory which should not be accessed - array elements outside of the array bounds or an object which was already deallocated or through a pointer which does point to a valid object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first problem is the return type of the main function
the second one is in:

```
double* d = new double;
```

you are allocating memory for one double but in your loops, you are accessing to 3 indexes
and last

```
 for (unsigned int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
```

the unsigned type can't hold negative value and so after it gets to zero it going up again to max unsigned int (x^32)-1 and you again accessing out of range places

so your code should look like that:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double* d = new double[3];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        d[i] = 1.5 + i;
    }
    for ( int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << d[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to deallocate the memory. `delete[] d;` before returning from main.

Comment: You don't need to allocate and delete that array. Just declare an array. `double d[3];`

Comment: Don't change the type of the second loop. Make the second loop just count up from 0. But make the index into the array `2 - i`.

Comment: In C++ the return at the end of `main()` is not required. If not provided the compiler will plant `return 0` automatically.

Comment: Prefer to use `\n` over `std::endl` the endl performs an unnecessary `flush`.

Comment: Prefer to use range based `for()` rather than iterative `for()`

Answer (score 0):

In this statement you are creating memory in heap only for one double variable. If you need 3 . Then you must allocate memory for 3 variable like.

```
    double* d = new double[3];
```

And the reason loop is infinite is because in second loop when value of i will go to -1 since the variable is unsigned it will get converted to very large positive number depending on your machine like in my machine 
it get converted to 4294967295.

```
     unsigned int i = -1;
     cout<<i; //try running this code and you will see value of i to be 4294967295
```

Error explanation

1. See your 3rd and 2nd last error say the same that value is converted to very large int.
2. Other error said as i explained above that you have allocated memory for 1 double ie 8byte but you are using it for 3 double (d[1],d[3],d[3]) which is 8 x 3 = 24 bytes.
3. Remaining is return type which must be int not void